# If MySQL timestring is older than 30 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, time

So I have a timestring that has the last time something wash it. So it's like:

```
$lasthit = '2015-09-25 12:15:04';
```

(so a MySQL timestring), if the timestring of `$lasthit` is older than `30 minutes` from the current time.  Then do `noHitsIn30Mins()`

Comment: and what's the question? where is any code that isn't working as expected?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Okay, so how do I generate a timestring similar to $lasthit with the current time?

Comment: @user1687621 : `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` but it looks like you want to compare the date objects, please edit your question because it's unclear now if you want to generate a time string of compare times.

Comment: Well, $lasthit timestring will look like that. So I'd need to compare the time to now, and see if that time is longer than 30 minutes from the current server time.

Comment: Where is your server located??

Answer (score 1):

```
$lasthit = strtotime("2015-09-25 12:15:04");
$thirtyminutes = strtotime("-30 minutes");

if ($lasthit  >= $thirtyminutes) {
    // HAPPY GF/BF
} else {
    // MAD GF/BF
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Always pulls that there is no hits no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

I had a work around for this here in my office. In essence, I didn't really care what the time was in format of date/time. That was pointless. I just needed to know if X amount of minutes had passed since I last saw them on the server and if so I needed to time them out.

So my column on the server to store the time was just a bigint. When the user hit my server the first time I would store:

```
time() + (60 * $minutes);
```

The next time they hit the server I would look at time() and if it was greater than what I had stored in the table then the user had timed out. I'd erase their "timestamp" on the server than they'd have to login again. If it was not greater than, then I would store a new value of `time() + (60 * $minutes);`

I really didn't care for what the exact date/time was. I was never going to read it verbatim. I was just concerned if it had been $minutes long.